# Как указать локальный сервер?

Tags: apache, php, dreamweaver

Сори за такой вопрос! Просто это мой первый сайт! Так вот, создал сервер по [этой инструкции](http://ab-w.net/PHP/server_set.php)  и регистрацию! Теперь чтоб проверить, нужно указать локальный серв! Где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скачать [Денвер](http://denwer.ru) и запускать все на нем. Это проще, чем настраивать запуск сервера. Для этого следует указать в качестве рабочей или тестовой папки локальную папку внутри home. Скажем, создать: `C:\WebServers\home\my.ru\www`. Вопрос скорее на БитКод.

А вообще - стандартно =)

1. Во вкладке серверы жмем на добавить сервер.
2. Connect using (соединение, то бишь) - Local/Network.
3. Server Folder - реальный путь к корню сайта.
4. Web URL - путь в строке браузера. Если локальный сайт называется locMySite.ru - так и пишем. По-умолчаниюстоит просто локалхост.
5. В Эдвансед можно проставить сервер-модел PHP-Mysql.
6. Еще надо в списке серверов не забыть проставить галочку "Testing".

Answer (score 0):

[Это установить](http://www.iis.net/), [это поверх](http://php.iis.net/). Для проверки - заглаза

Answer (score 0):

D:/server/apache/htdocs в вашем так будет.